# Uber app login not redirecting to my app if Uber app is in background and not in home screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, cocoapods, uber-api

I am implementing the Uber ride request feature in my app (using Uber pod). Then I have to login to Uber from my app. If the Uber app is not in the logged in state or in home screen, the login process from my app to Uber app is working perfectly. I will get the callback in my app delegate.  Everything is working fine. (redirect url, token and other plist params everything ok)

But the problem is if **the Uber app is logged in and then I have selected any other screen like side pane or settings, then I put that app in background**. That time, if I click the login button in my app it will redirect to Uber app then it is stuck there. Not redirecting back to my app as logged in success.

Same behaviour experienced in the test app provided by Uber with their sdk. We are near to production state, any idea?

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this problem, we are aware of the issue - and it is on our roadmap to be fixed. We don't have one ETA when this is going to be done. You can monitor our Git repository for the new releases - and news - so it will be listed there when the problem is solved.

Comment: Ok fine. Thank you for your reply. @SasaJovanovic . We will wait for the next release with this update.